# Fluid on a deforming mesh Problem?

Tags: modifiers, physics, fluid-simulation

Im trying to show a downspout eroding the soil away as an example.

I have tried:
A. Using a boolean to deform over time the (ground mesh(obstacle) OR animating shape keys for the (ground mesh(obstacle).

B. I then baked the fluid simulation and it does not follow the animated deformation?

It is driving me nuts, i did get this to work in MODO but I am falling in love  with Blender and its community.

Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple. In the *Fluid Obstacle* settings, check *Export Animated Mesh*.

Also, make sure the obstacle is not set as *Volume*, or concave areas won't work as expected.